# CopyAsync method don`t replace existing file. UWP. Application-storage

Tags: c#, uwp

Now I am working on edit operation in my app. So in edit operation there is  an ability to change image and in the same time name of the file that keep image of the contact can not be renamed(during one session of operation image files will be changing but all this file will take same name).

And I used overload of `CopyAsync` method (docs to this method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.copyasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_CopyAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFolder_System_String_Windows_Storage_NameCollisionOption_)) that as I have understand must to replace file to the existing file with the same name.

I get `imageFile` variable by `FileOpenPicker`. Code below runs every time I have choosed image by `FileOpenPicker`. And when I re-choose image at the result `Image` UI control show me previous chosen image. I expect that `Image` will view last image that I have choosed but this does not occurred.

```
    public BitmapImage Image { set; get; }

    //Copy of the file that saved in temporary storage
    StorageFile fileForView = await imageFile.CopyAsync 
       (ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder,
       fileName,
       NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileForView.Path));
```

Maybe I understand logic of `CopyAsync` method not correctly if I am in this case please show me how make my plan working with this method if it is possible. Otherwise offer your solution cause I have no idea now how to do this.

Also I tried to do this with `CopyAndReplaceAsync` method. But still no result. I do it in this way:

```
         if (null != await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName))
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

            await storageFile.CopyAndReplaceAsync(imageFile);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not being overridden? I think that maybe you are not re-opening the file properly. Can you show your code to load the image?

Comment: You mean that it might be problem that image did not being replaced? I thought that file that `CopyAsync` returns is not need in any appendix operation to make it workable. `Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileForView.Path));`

Comment: Are you changing the image at all before you save it or are you just resaving the same image? You could always do `File.Delete(storageFile)` if you wanted to give it a try, but it seems to me that it is overwriting it - it's just the same image.

Comment: Yeah I am resaving image. I have tried your method. And for more confidence after deleting I checked temporary folder and it didn't keep any file. So even I copy new file to the temp folder it still show me the previous one. Also I used `DeleteAsync` method of `StorageFile` class. And still no result.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect that Image will view last image that I have choosed but this does not occurred.

The above `CopyAsync` method is correct, and I have tested with the following code, it works well.

```
private async void ListOption_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        StorageFile fileForView = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileForView.Path));
        TestImg.Source = Image;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```